# CapsLock for numbers doesn't work on Belgian MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-languages

I have a Belgian AZERTY keyboard on my MacBook Pro. Sadly, it appears to be impossible to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to type numbers. I still need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> for every number I want to type. Is it possible to change the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key’s function to Shift Lock so that it affects the whole keyboard rather than just the letters? I’d like to be able to type numbers without holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

This question has been answered before. The answer was:

> In System Preferences, Keyboard, set your keyboard to French Numerical.

But I don't find 'French Numerical' there.

Answer (score 2):

Belgian & French are amongst the very few languages that need you to press Shift or CapsLock to access the numbers. They are also amongst the few that use AZERTY, so your choices are limited.

Of the two, Belgian only switches to numbers with the Shift key, French Numerical works with either Shift or CapsLock.

Both should be available to you in System Prefs > Keyboard > Input Sources
Click the + button, then just start typing f…r…e… & it will appear in the list.
All layouts & languages are already included in macOS, you never need to download from anywhere.

[image]